# Mechanism for returning a string from C main() program

Tags: c

I know that C program generally ends with return, where we return the status of the program.
However, I want to return a string. The reason is that, I will be calling the C-executable from a shell script and printing the returned string.
Is there any mechanism for the same ?

Comment: Just to add, One of the way, is to write the string to a temporary file and read/delete it from shell script.But i want to avoid such stuff, as the string will be a password.

Comment: See the bottom of my comment about using passwords in shell scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such mechanism; the return code is expected to be a byte. If you want to output a string from your program then use something like `printf()` and command substitution in the shell script to capture it.

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked.. however, do we need to take any precautions for the same ? This is for production like utility.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ok, Actually the functionality, I asked above, is going to be production implemented.So, wanted to know, if i go with "printf" approach, will there be any problems, that you might foresee.

Comment: Cool then.. I think no other program uses/fires printf statement... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TonyK: The type is `int`, but not many (if any) shells provide access to a value outside of 0 through 255.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot.

The best thing you could do is writing the string somewhere (on standard output, standard error or some file); then the shellscript will get your string from there.

Standard output (thus using just a `printf`) is probably the best solution, since it will be very easy from your C program print the string, and very easy for the shellscript getting that data:

From shell script:

```
STRING="$( ./your_program argv1 argv2 )"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is not way to return a string from `main()`. Maybe the program itself should print the string ?

Answer (score 4):

Just output the string you want to return to standard output with `printf`.  Then in your script, do something like this:

```
SOMESTRING="`./yourprogram`"
```

The backticks will capture the output of the program, which will be the string you printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but you don't need to either.  You return a stat code from main, but you can always re-direct the output and capture it in your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - you can only return an integer.

Remember that C was developed alongside Unix. Unix programs return an integer value which is intended as a status code. If a program was to return string(s) it would write them to stdout, and then the user (or a script) would pipe it into something useful.

MS DOS also had number-only status values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the string to `stdout` and use the shell's command substitution to read the result:

```
"`command`"
```

or:

```
"$(command)"
```

Either way, you should use the enclosing double-quotes as above. Note that this method has a potentially-serious problem that it removes all training newlines from the command's output. If you need to preserve the exact output, try:

```
output="$(command ; echo x)"
output="${output%x}"
```

Since OP mentioned that this is for a password, another piece of advice: once you've read a password into a shell variable, **never** pass it on the command line to other programs. Command lines are usually world-readable. Instead of something like

```
wget "http://$user:$pass@host/foo"
```

try something like

```
wget -i - << EOF
http://$user:$pass@host/foo
EOF
```

Here-files as in this example are useful with a number of programs which need to take passwords from scripts.